# How to pass null as DateTime value?

Tags: datetime, null

In a database, there is a field that saves a closure date. This date can be NOT NULL only if the case has been closed. If the case is not closed, it has to be NULL. How can I pass null value to a DateTime object?

Tried this but it doesn't work.

```
DateTime closure= dateDatumIspisa.SelectedDate ?? null;
DateTime closure= dateDatumIspisa.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Parse("");
DateTime closure= dateDatumIspisa.SelectedDate ?? DBNull.Value;
DateTime closure= dateDatumIspisa.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Parse(DBNull.Value.ToString());
```

Also tried GetValueOrDefault() but it inserts DateTime.Min value, while I need this field left empty.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare

```
DateTime ? closure = dateDatumIspisa.SelectedDate;
```

**no need here to use the ??** in this line !

Answer (score 3):

Just make `closure` a `DateTime?` instead of a `DateTime`. The whole point of `Nullable<T>` is to make a nullable type from a non-nullable one.

Now, you haven't shown the type of `SelectedDate` - but if it's already a `DateTime?` then you don't need to use `??` at all. Just:

```
DateTime? closure= dateDatumIspisa.SelectedDate;
```

How familiar are you with nullable value types in general? You might want to read up on the [MSDN coverage of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).